# Parsing JSON from url then show it to TextView

Tags: android, json

I want to ask about JSON parsing. If I have a web service like this from url = `http://localhost/bus/format/json`:

```
{
  "status":"success",
  "sessionid":"489GHJ8969"
  "schedule":{
     "went":{
        "description":"this is bus schedule",
        "bus":{
           "1":"A30",
           "2":"A40"
        },
        "depart":{
           "1":"8AM",
           "2":"11AM"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

how to get and parse this JSON in Android then show it to textview? I had search in here but I still am confused how to parse JSON.

This is update after i tried to parse the JSON but still no clue about how to parse JSON

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();          

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

    }
}
```

bus activity

```
public class Bus extends Activity {

String url, s;

  //private static final String TAG_STATUS = "Status";
private static final String TAG_SCHEDULE = "schedule";
private static final String TAG_WENT = "went";
private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.jadwal);      

    TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    url = "http://localhost/bus/format/json";

    tx.setText(url);

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try {
        JSONObject jadwal = json.getJSONObject(TAG_SCHEDULE);
        JSONObject went = jadwal.getJSONObject(TAG_WENT);
        s = went.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}    
}
```

and then the result

```
10-13 00:51:15.212: W/System.err(373): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: /127.0.0.1:80 - Connection refused
10-13 00:51:15.212: W/System.err(373):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:254)
10-13 00:51:15.212: W/System.err(373):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:533)
10-13 00:51:15.212: W/System.err(373):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1055)
10-13 00:51:15.222: W/System.err(373):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
10-13 00:51:15.222: W/System.err(373):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:143)
10-13 00:51:15.222: W/System.err(373):  ... 21 more
10-13 00:51:15.222: E/Buffer Error(373): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
10-13 00:51:15.222: E/JSON Parser(373): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
10-13 00:51:15.222: D/AndroidRuntime(373): Shutting down VM
10-13 00:51:15.222: W/dalvikvm(373): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
```

Comment: Use [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Comment: write "How to parse JSON in android" into google.

Comment: i had tried the example in this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ but i still don't understand how to use JSONObject and JSONArray and then put it to textview.so please help me :)

Answer (score 2):

look at http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/
For Example:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(yourResponse);
String status = object.getString("status");
JSONObject schedule = object.getJSONObject("schedule");
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Android has JSON parser built in:
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html

It wirks but utilizes DOM model ( and thus not suitable for bigger data )
If you need more comfort or databinging gran google GSON  or use my small library:

https://github.com/ko5tik/jsonserializer